# Is it possible for the Lagrange multiplier to satisfy some constraints themselves?

Tags: calculus-of-variations, classical-mechanics

I am using the field-theoretic langauge, so that we think of some action functional
\begin{equation}
S[f_l,T_{ij}]=\int_0^1 dt \int_{[0,1]^3}d^3\overrightarrow{x}\mathcal{L}(f_l(\overrightarrow{x}, t),T_{ij}(\overrightarrow{x}, t),\frac{\partial f_l}{\partial t}, \partial_k f_l)
\end{equation}
subject to the constraints
\begin{equation}
T_{ij}-\frac{\partial_i f_j + \partial_j f_i}{2}=0.
\end{equation}

All field components are set to be real-valued and smooth. (I do not substitute this constraint directly into the Lagrangian because I want to do variations with respect to $T_{ij}$ as well.)

In order to realize this constraint, we can introduce a symmetric tensor $\Psi_{ij}(\overrightarrow{x}, t)$ as Lagrange multipliers so that the modified action is
\begin{equation}
S_{mod}[f_l,T_{ij},\Psi_{ij}]=\int_0^1 dt \int_{[0,1]^3}d^3\overrightarrow{x}\Bigl[\mathcal{L}(f_l,T_{ij},\frac{\partial f_l}{\partial t}, \partial_k f_l)-\Psi_{ij} \cdot \Bigl(T_{ij}-\frac{\partial_i f_j + \partial_j f_i}{2}\Bigr)\Bigr].
\end{equation}

Here, I want to put additional constraints on the Lagrange multiplieres "themselves" that $\Psi_{ij}$ that $\partial_i \Psi_{ij}=0$.

I wonder if this is possible. For example, if we think of another symmetric tensor field $F_{ij}$ and construct $\Psi_{ij}$ as
\begin{equation}
\Psi_{ij}:=\epsilon_{ilk} \epsilon_{jwr} \partial_l \partial_w F_{kr},
\end{equation}
we can surely satisfy the constraint $\partial_i \Psi_{ij}=0$. Moreover, I checked that $\Psi_{ij}$ of this form does NOT have any component identically vanishing.

Nevertheless, I am not certain whether $\Psi_{ij}$ of this form can be used as Lagrange multipliers.. I have never seen a case in which the Lagrange multipliers themselves are required to satisfy some constraints.

Could anyone please explain?

Comment: I don't understand the notion of "wanting to put constraints on Lagrange multipliers". Lagrange multipliers must have the same number of degrees of freedom as the number of constraints (in the original problem). If you start to reduce the freedom in the Lagrange multipliers, you're simply not enforcing all the constraints anymore. In the extreme case of demanding that the Lagrange multipliers vanish, you're not enforcing anything anymore. The only way you're going to be able to reduce the freedom in the Lagrange multipliers is if there's too much freedom to begin with.